# Combine Line and Column Chart antd (ant design)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, antd

I have generated two charts- one line chart and one column chart. They are both on the same x axis (time), so i wanted to combine the two. I am using Ant Design Charts (React). Any advice here? I would want a y axis on each side of the graph to show the different scales (since the line chart goes to 700-800 while the bar chart goes to 8-10)

The image below shows what the two graphs currently look like.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 3):

You can use Multi View Plot- **Combo Plot** chart, which combines line chart and column chart. Also, it provides dual y-axis capability(each type of chart can set it's own y-axis field and max value).

```
import { Mix } from '@ant-design/plots';
```

For more details, see
https://charts.ant.design/en/examples/plugin/multi-view#combo-plot

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34450343)

Answer (score 2):

You can Use Grouped Column Line chart..

https://charts.ant.design/en/examples/dual-axes/grouped-column-line#grouped-column-line